# Weight sharing in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to implement the following architecture:[image: Symmetric neural net layer]

I'm passing a concatenated input

```
[x y]
```

into a neural net and the fist layer needs to be symmetric in a way suggested in the image, with N_HIDDEN neurons in the layer. I started with the following setup:

```
input = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 2*NUM_FEATURES])
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[2*NUM_FEATURES, N_HIDDEN], minval=-0.0001, maxval=0.0001, dtype=tf.float32))

hidden = tf.matmul(input,weights)
```

However, the above code is not symmetric in the way the image suggests.  If I make my weights only half the size, then I have to multiply the inputs x and y separately.

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[NUM_FEATURES, N_HIDDEN], minval=-0.0001, maxval=0.0001, dtype=tf.float32))
```

What is the way in tensorflow to share the neuron for both x_k and y_k?

Comment: So you want to use shared weights in the first layer and then concatenate the outputs from that layer to use them for further computations in your model?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.
I just have no idea how to correctly define the weights so that it corresponds to the image.

Comment: Maybe you could try to seperate the inputs. When you create the weights and use them in two different operations (for each input one matmul) you should be able to concatenate the outputs of the first layer (tf.concat). This might be a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a misunderstanding of how Tensorflow implements a neural network like yours.
There is no explicit definition of a Neuron as it is pictured in your image. `h_i` and `h_i'` are represented as operations.
In your case you can think of every `h` as a sum of `x1 * v_x1 + x2 * v_x2 + ...`, `y1 * v_y1 + y2 * v_y2 + ...` and `b`.

In code it could be implemented as:

```
input_x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, NUM_FEATURES])
input_y = tf.placeholder('float', [None, NUM_FEATURES])

weights_x = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[NUM_FEATURES, N_HIDDEN], dtype=tf.float32)) # v_x
weights_y = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[NUM_FEATURES, N_HIDDEN], dtype=tf.float32)) # v_y
bias      = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[N_HIDDEN], dtype=tf.float32))

hidden_x = tf.matmul(input_x, weights_x)
hidden_y = tf.matmul(input_y, weights_y)

h = tf.add(hidden_x, hidden_y)
h = tf.add(h, bias)

batch_size = 5
x = np.random.normal(size = [batch_size, NUM_FEATURES])
y = np.random.normal(size = [batch_size, NUM_FEATURES])

session = tf.InteractiveSession()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

session.run(h, feed_dict = {input_x : x, input_y : y})
```

Whenever you run the `h` node, it is equal to calculating all of the `h_i` in the image.
So, there is no need to concatenate your data to make it symmetrical. 
Using two separate placeholders for different types of input will make it easier to understand how your network works. And the weights can be separated, too. In your image they are also labeled differently: `v_x` and `v_y`.
I hope it helps!